# Using upvotes to fight bad questions

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

I've seen several discussions on how to stop the flood of bad questions and thereby improve signal to noise. Currently we can close them but it's seems at least on some popular tags that it's hard to keep up. The questioner is still getting answers and therefor getting what they are looking for but harming those that take the time to research the basics of the problem and ask a specific question rather than a "help me debug my code

One way I see that this could be changed is that users with a rep of less than X can ask questions but only get answers is the question get more than Y upvotes.

Does the community believe an approach like that would be appropriate / valuable?

**EDIT**
I'm not trying to equate low rep and bad questions but those that have high rep have been around for some time and know the rules and as long as it's worth the effort to post the low quality question there's less incentive to do the effort of analysing the problem before posting

Comment: You seem to be equating/correlating low rep with bad questions.

Comment: I think this would be a nightmare for many questions very thoroughly researched even in popular tags, because, those questions might only be understandable to some particular/high experienced users in that field and might not get that much of upvotes to be eligible for an answer, because other users might not be even able to understand that question.

Comment: I can't make sense of your first paragraph, in particular the last sentence.

Comment: I want to give you an answer but you don't have enough upvotes.

Comment: @Oded Because there's no correlation at all between low rep and bad questions, right?

Comment: @user3477950 - the problem is that it punishes all new users. Many of which can, in fact, put a good question together.

Comment: @user3477950 - also, correlation != causation. Low rep doesn't indicate that the question is bad. In the same way that high rep doesn't indicate that a question is good. Sure, statistically speaking, that may be so, but that ignores that there are many people who don't fit the statistic.

Comment: @Oded If they can put a good question together, they will get an upvote. This threshold doesn't have to be high - "1" is enough to get rid of answers to questions so bad, that they are instantly at -5. Yes, statistically speaking that's the case with low rep/bad question correlation. Even if a good question from a good user won't get through (but I doubt - even without complete understanding you usually can see that a question is well written), the community overall will gain.

Comment: [I even once calculated this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow/202442#202442) in the context of a similar idea.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Why would they get upvotes? Who is going to bother to click on the question they can't answer because it has 0 score just so they can upvote it and sit reloading the page until it has `Y` upvotes? This would also lead to vote inflation; people would upvote borderline questions just so they could post answers.

Comment: @Wooble I do upvote good questions, even if I can't answer them, and I believe that's the way things should work. People can sit reloading the page even a week if they want, but if the question is bad, it shouldn't be answered.

Comment: This is an intriguing suggestion, but I think votes are the wrong metric. You got me wondering if it wouldn't be a good idea to hide the answers to *closed* questions from the asker. Closure confirms that experienced members of the community found the question fundamentally inappropriate. There will always be reputation whores who answer these questions, but askers shouldn't be able to benefit anyway from having asked them.

Comment: @Wooble That's actually a very good point

Comment: Suggested quite a while ago on Meta.SE (then Meta.SO, of course) as well: [Require a net +1 for questions in high volume tags to become answerable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108822) See also [Novice questions approval queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214813)

Answer (score 3):

This concept, as I see it, is not a good one.  It would require upvoting a question and then hoping the question gets enough votes to actually see an answer.  I'm not sure how that would benefit the community.

If the questions are bad, yet good enough to eventually allow answers to be given, then just edit the question and make it better.  As long as you don't change the underlying request for knowledge, there's nothing wrong with making a question better worded or more clear in what it's requesting.

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea in the version when the threshold is set to "0" or "1" (or even "-1"). Most of the time if a question is acceptable, it is being edited, fixed and answered. Questions that are not salvageable gain downvotes quickly, but are not closed fast enough.

As far as I remember from some other discussion we don't want answers to plainly bad questions (because of rep harvesting for example) which results in encouraging people to keep posting junk. This seems like a good option to try.

Comment: Your second paragraph is exactly the problem I was try to phrase a solution to

Answer (score 3):

This feature request has a bunch of unintended consequences that we do not know about, and one that I do think would happen.

Lets say people REALLY WANT an answer to THEIR question. Which they almost always do...

To improve the odds that their question would be answered, they could simply downvote all the new questions that come in after theirs and even some questions that came before theirs.

And your solution is easy to bypass as well, like what Wooble mentioned in the comments

> This would also lead to vote inflation; people would upvote borderline
>   questions just so they could post answers.

Also, it takes time to get the gist of how SE works. SE is good because you can get very good answers very fast. Anything that attempts to slow down people getting help (*except for those that have infractions obviously*) is not good for the site. It would be very user un-friendly.

Comment: I did not say that the sum of the up and down votes should be the threshold I said upvotes solely. Kind of a "open" button. So the threshold could be simply one up vote. That does not counter the potential inflation though

Answer (score -4):

I think this idea may be onto something, but I would suggest ALL questions (regardless of poster rep) require at least one upvote to be answered. That upvote could, but need not, come from the answerer themselves.

It would further address the problem being discussed here:

[Why don't questions get that much upvote love?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359703/why-dont-questions-get-that-much-upvote-love/)

where most (including myself) seem to agree that poor questions shouldn't be receiving answers but many people answer them anyway just to rack up votes.

At least by requiring a single upvote - even if from the answerer - this behavior would be deterred, since someone answering a 0 or negative vote question just to score some points would have to swallow their pride and hit that button.

---

To anyone who disagrees with this, do you not agree that poor questions shouldn't receive answers just for the sake of someone racking up answer votes? Otherwise why would you not agree that a question should require some acknowledgement of quality (including from the answerer if no one else) before being answered?

Comment: Frustrating for new users, no? They see a clear and useful question that they are perfectly capable of answering but can't upvote it so they can't answer it either. They leave dissatisfied thinking this is a clique they haven't been invited to. If they go looking for other questions they will find that all the ones they are permitted to answer already have answers.

Comment: @RobertLongson good point. Might be worth checking the stats to see how many >0 point answers come from users who can't vote.