# Why don't questions get that much upvote love?

Tags: discussion, questions, upvotes

I'm often noticing that some questions get 0 or 1 upvote and 4 or 5 answers, with some answers scoring 3 or more upvotes.

In that case, why don't the answerers themselves upvote the question?

If it's not a good question, why does it get 5 answers when 1 answer would be enough to help the OP already?

If it's a good question, why not upvote it, possibly *after* having answered for the FGITW answerers, which increases question visibility, and hence answer visibility?

Comment: personally, i prefer to save my votes for casting downvotes since there seems to be far less people downvoting low quality content compared to people casting upvotes. Nothing worse than running across a low quality post when you've run out of votes. I will upvote though if i come across something exceptional.

Comment: bikeshedding... 5 trivial marginally-ok answers on trivial marginally-ok question... neither deserve upvotes - sounds as voting is working as expected.

Comment: I've completely given up on reasoning about question votes in the Python tag. Some FGITW-friendly "how do I get Y output from X input?" that can be approached a number of ways will garner lots of upvotes, while a question nearly the same but worded slightly differently will be pummeled with downvotes.

Comment: @miradulo:  [You may be interested in this Meta discussion.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/353940/1079354)

Comment: @Makoto Never saw that, thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I have to really search for questions I find it worthy to upvote. I find more answers that are worth it than questions.

Comment: Simply because people utilises the answer, but don't care about the question. In the most cases they upvote a question if they also encounter the same problem, but a suitable answer doesn't exist yet.

Comment: No one seems to be addressing the "why don't answerers upvote the question for visibility" part. I always did this when answering questions, but I'm not sure it's common. No idea why, I'm also curious.

Comment: @aw04 Because "visibility" doesn't feel like enough of a reason to upvote. In this spirit, it is pretty annoying when someone upvotes a horrible question after providing an answer.

Comment: @miradulo right but I would think most answerers fall into either a) self serving, willing to answer bad questions for points or b) only going to answer questions they think are good (I like to think I fall into this one). so in either case, why wouldn't that person upvote the question?

Comment: @miradulo and of course I'm not arguing the people in the first group should be doing that, only wondering why they wouldn't take advantage?

Comment: see what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479584/python-how-to-find-the-position-of-the-second-lowest-value-in-a-list/47479633#47479633: 4 answers: score +1/-2 :)

Comment: Hah, I actually consider a 0 vote new question a blessing these days - some of the stuff I see is so bad as to invoke second hand embarrassment...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ if you don't want to see bad questions, first rule: don't connect on weekends :)

Comment: I sometimes answer a question which I find rather bad just to get it out of my unanswered questions queue.

Comment: yes, that's one of the "good" reasons I would answer too. But if there are already 6 answers, there's no need. It's useful only if you're the first to answer something valid;

Comment: Such comments as: _To be honest, I have to really search for questions I find it worthy to upvote._ caused that me stopped contributing to StackOverflow intensively. Me personally hate the shift of the SO to group of _elitists_ (in the bad meaning of words - unfortunately), who forget than very few people born as genius and all needs to learn.

Comment: @jm666 yes, asking good questions is more difficult than answering bad ones. And you expose yourself to free/stealth downvotes... on the other hand without the questions pouring in, the site becomes a museum of the state of the computer world round 2012.

Comment: they do when they are interesting/fun

Comment: I personally only upvote questions and answers that I concider to be of good quality and can be useful for other users. Just because I can answer a question doesn't mean it was of a good quality. Most often the question are way too closely tied to a very specific use case to be of use to others.

Answer (score 38):

Sometimes the question is on-topic enough to answer, but not all that useful in today's tech field.  This covers circumstances like the umpteenth Java logic problem or off-by-one errors which, while on-topic, are still not valuable questions.  That's a circumstance under which I don't normally upvote a question.

Comment: There are many, many more good answers than good questions.

Comment: True @MiloChristiansen but if nobody asked questions anymore there would be no answers good or otherwise and this site would die, so it's good to encourage people asking questions.

Comment: @Mishax true. And the site dies if there are too many bad questions & answers too (pollution). It's a delicate balance to find.

Comment: @Makoto: so you're answering and not upvoting? is that what you mean?

Comment: While I agree with the basic idea that answering without upvoting is valid, we do actually have, not 1, but 2 (or often 3-4) close reasons for code dump questions that are resolved in a manner that's not helpful to anyone else, like logic problems or off-by-one errors. You shouldn't be answering such questions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  In essence, yes.  These are questions which *aren't* off-topic, but aren't that great.

Comment: @Dukeling:  I can't close *every* question that I don't like.  That's not the point of this.  There are questions which are truly, 100% bonafide on-topic for the site, but I just don't *like*.  Closing those kinds of questions is an abuse of the close privilege.

Comment: @Makoto I was addressing the on-topicness of your examples, not what you like or don't like. My point is: there are generally multiple applicable close reasons for those questions, questions that have even 1 applicable close reason should be closed.

Answer (score 11):

I upvote questions if they are useful (to me), clear and well researched.

I upvote answers if they are useful (to me), clear and well researched.

I don't upvote questions just because I answered them. Why should I?

In principle, that is all I can say on the topic except maybe for a speculation. Maybe people show less love on average by not upvoting questions enough because they feel the questioner has been awarded enough by getting the answers. But this is pure speculation.

Comment: Unfortunately couldn't upvote the question because I think it doesn't show clear enough where the problem is. Posted the answer to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: tI upvote if they're useful to me, and that's it. Love it. Go

Answer (score 10):

It's not a rule, but often I find that a question that has 5 answers shouldn't have been asked, because it's likely common-enough knowledge and can be found easily on SO or elsewhere.

In other situations, the question isn't particularly well written, and I don't think it's worth an upvote. 
People who come here to ask questions do so because they want an answer. The answer is probably more rewarding than any upvote would be. I do upvote questions that are particularly well written, contain a good, contextual explanation, you know, top quality stuff.

For answers that's (slightly) different. If you answer a question, you give up your time to help somebody else. Of course an answer still has to be correct and good, but the boundary for upvote-worthy I think is slightly lower than for questions.

Comment: "a question that has 5 answers shouldn't have been asked": true, but only for newer questions. Check old legacy questions with 40+ answers :)

Comment: In old legacy times there were different rules. I'm always a bit conservative when casting votes or making changes to those.

Answer (score 9):

A lot of good comments & answers here, which inspired my to answer my own question.

The post is focused on people who *answer* the question but *don't upvote*.

**The bad reasons:**

- Some people *answering a question* won't upvote it because they just don't care, they just hope to get some rep. But if the question has an unfair negative score, it's less likely that someone cares to visit the page and see the answer, so it's better to correct the voting.
- Some people don't want to waste votes on questions: same general idea: if a post is good, just upvote, if a post is bad, downvote. Don't make plans about the rest of the day (unless if you've got 2 votes left, yes, that could be a good reason). If you're out of votes, wait till tomorrow.

**The okay reasons (i.e. the ones that I fell for sometimes :)):**

- they judge that the question has enough upvotes. 5 answers on an okay (but not excellent) question, maybe doesn't deserve 5 upvotes. If it gets 2 or 3 upvotes, OP is already rewarded.
- The question is not very good and doesn't deserve upvotes (they even can downvote a question they answered). This is justifiable to provide an answer to a averagely bad question, only if there isn't any other answer that fits. Else it's just more noise.

I tend to upvote *any* question where I answered & where I get votes months after having answered. It probably means that a google search led to this question: adds value to the site.

And yes sometimes a very bad question gets a very good answer (else why the "lifeboat"/"lifejacket" badges ?), and it doesn't suddenly become a good question (those cases are rather rare, it takes talent to answer like that)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call good planning a bad reason. Why would you upvote a mediocre post when you can upvote a good one? It might be a different story if these people only use a small fraction of their votes, but if they get close to or reach the limit daily, selective voting makes more sense than first-come-first-served.

Comment: okay, maybe in that case of "you have 3 votes left today".

Comment: The 40 vote limit affects different patterns of activity differently. If you actively answer questions and end up answering multiple questions a day, it's likely you'll see less overall questions throughout the day and likely also never run out of votes. If you instead seek out questions that need to be improved or closed, you'll very quickly come across 40 posts worth voting on. You'll get some of them back due to posts being deleted, but often it takes more than a day for posts to be deleted (assuming they ever get deleted) so you don't get very many of them back through deletion.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that if you answer, you should usually upvote the question. I use this rule of thumb all the time. As a funny consequence, if I want to answer a question which is worded or formatted badly, this rule reminds me that I should improve the question by editing.

For me, the exceptional cases are when all existing answers are incorrect. In these cases, I feel the need to post a correct answer even if the question is not good, especially when the incorrect answers have high scores.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a regular visitor, while pretty new (btw, I find this leveling process slow), and I mostly find the question I was looking for (or one that's close enough that the answer may solve my issue).

I don't even get to think about rating the question, since the immediate need is to see if there's any helpful information, which usually is in the answers and comments. **Those I do up-vote**.

Then, I find that up-voting the answer should be enough to demonstrate my interest in the topic, so maybe the website should concern itself with identifying how useful the question is by how many times it's been visited and maybe number of comments and votes on answers as well.

Why should I bother with remembering to vote every question I am interested in, when its significance could be determined that way.
Of course, I should still be able to up/down-vote a question. The only times I've pondered up-voting a question is when I haven't found a helpful answer, or later, when I've already left the page...

Answer (score -7):

I was wondering this very thing and came across this. Of course what follows is all my opinion and not intended as a judgment of any individual, nor a policy proposal.

But that said, I feel that except in egregious cases, it's rude, possibly even insulting, to answer a question without upvoting it.

First, by answering, you are inherently acknowledging that the question was at least worth your time to read and answer. You presumably believe your answer was useful. By definition, then, you must believe the question was useful because it led to a useful answer. Except by not upvoting, you give no credit to the questioner for their contribution.

Second, upvoting costs you essentially nothing. "Saving" your daily votes really doesn't seem like a valuable enough thing to justify not giving credit to a person who had both the guts to post a question (which is always an exercise in breathholding) and the wisdom to post a question that was worth your time to answer. Believe it or not, this matters to people, especially the newer ones.

It's obvious that downvoting of questions is grossly disproportional to downvoting of answers, even for questions with answers. It's obvious why - the former costs nothing. Or at least it costs nothing more than an upvote does.

It's also obvious that there's an epidemic of bad questions, and it's only getting worse. They are justified in being pummelled and closed. But we're not talking about those. We're talking about questions that someone thought worthy of an answer.

The specific scenario of a person answering a question but not upvoting it - to me that fosters, and/or is a symptom of, a basic lack of comity and collegiality. I'm not suggesting any policy change here. This is just about etiquette. In my opinion, when a question is worth an answer, throwing the poster a bone with an upvote seems logically justified almost as a matter of course, costs essentially nothing, and is just all around a decent thing to do. I hope people will consider these comments and maybe be a little bit more liberal with that up arrow on questions they answer.

PS - I fully expect this isn't going to be a popular view, but I'm also interested to hear other viewpoints, such as KevinB's below.

---

Follow up -
Perfect example of the problem:

[How to generate tree in c# from a list in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644344/how-to-generate-tree-in-c-sharp-from-a-list-in-console/75644829#75644829)

Four answers, three of which came from fairly high rep folks, none of whom UVd. Question was ultimately closed for lack of clarity, with several DVs, after the four answers were posted.  I freely admit I DVd ever answer because of the harm I think this practice causes. My comment was deleted, which was obviously meta, so I don't mind, but I'm highlighting it here where it belongs.

Comment: I both agree, and disagree. *"First, by answering, you are inherently acknowledging that the question was at least worth your time to read and answer. You presumably believe your answer was useful. By definition, then, you must believe the question was useful because it led to a useful answer."* Except... people often answer *anything they can* simply because it will earn them reputation and help someone, ignoring whether or not the contribution will be valuable to the community, or if it's a duplicate, or off topic, etc

Comment: I would instead phrase this as... Answerers should only answer questions that are high enough quality to upvote and aren't closable.

Comment: @KevinB I totally get what you're saying and I would agree - and heck, I won't deny I have done and occasionally do it myself - but to not upvote in that case almost makes it worse, wouldn't you say? A person gets a potential for credit but with a wink and a nod by not upvoting sort of acknowledges that their motive for answering wasn't great. If you're gaming the system the least you could do is give a free gift to the person that helped you do it.

Comment: Effectively, i agree that users should upvote posts that they answer, but only because i also think users shouldn't answer questions that aren't worthy of upvotes. Because i don't trust that answerers follow that advice, i'm not necessarily a fan of encouraging answerers to always upvote the questions they answer either.

Comment: I think I agree to a point @kevinB. Of course this is a little off topic, but I certainly never answer a question if I don't think I can offer something useful, but I don't always give consideration to whether it might be a duplicate or closable for some other reason like lack of detail. But again, different topic. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Upvoted with the caveat that this really also implies: don’t answer what you wouldn’t upvote.

Comment: FWIW, I think it is also important that if one wants to answer but the question isn’t in shape yet, then the answerer can edit the question appropriately as well first.

Comment: Also agree with both comments @mistermyagi but I do find it notable that all comments so far have focused on the question's objective value to the site and not the social element. One might legitimately argue that this is not a social media platform and our goal shouldn't be to get likes. But would not more liberal recognition of peoples efforts foster a more welcoming community? Some day the 100kers are gonna retire. What motive do newer people have to be active here if they perceive it as too much of a grind to get any meaningful recognition? And I speak for myself in some ways.

Comment: @JustAnswertheQuestion you should change your username to "JustFollowTheRules". Because that is what we should all do. We don't own the site. I hear your plight, but we have to operate within the confines of the borders that have been put around us. So in this case, we don't recognise a person's efforts through voting. We are rating the quality of the content. That is the rule.

Comment: @Gimby cute :) But it's a straw man, because I never suggested people should upvote things they don't find useful. But we do all seem to agree that people shouldn't use low quality questions to rack up answer votes. So if anyone is not following the rules it's them.

Answer (score -18):

I don't upvote a question if it is not good enough described, hard to understand or if information are missing.

Comment: okay, but that's not the question: the question is "why don't you upvote a question you're answering to ?"

Comment: for the reasons I just described.

Comment: @Black. But if you answered (and received upvotes), then it's quite likely that the question *was* described well enough, it *was* understandable, and *didn't* have vital information missing.

Comment: No, it is even likely that I have downvoted it, because it had bad quality.

Comment: @Black. If it's so bad that you downvoted it, then why did you waste your time answering it?

Comment: @ekhumoro, because I knew the correct answer and I like to help others.

Comment: Grammar is important. Errors in the above post include:  not described *well* enough, *difficult* to understand, information *is* missing.  Questions that make those sort of basic literacy errors don't get votes from me. People here are suppose to be experts in their field. Basic literacy is a prerequisite.