# Why doesn't a question earn some additional reputation when its answers get votes?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, reputation

If a question you asked is generating a lot of answers with high votes, why doesn't the question earn reputation for this? I would think people visiting the site may not remember to upvote a good question when they find their answer.

This is not to say a question should earn the full reputation of each answer, but possibly a portion of the best answers.

**Edit**

I put together some [supporting data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/879784/proportion-of-question-upvotes-to-answer-upvotes) for my claim that questions are systematically underrated even though this question is now closed. It seems that at all levels of high question scores, answers are usually rated more highly.

**UPDATE** Questions are now rewarded with a full 10 reputation points. https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/

Comment: I have a feeling that the same will happen with this question ...

Comment: Ha, yes apparently so @Temani. To clarify, I'm not saying every point gained on an answer should be attributed to a question owner. It just seems that if a good question generates great answers, then it's likely worth more than the total votes that it has earned (because users will peck for an answer before voting on the question). I've observed that questions often have fewer votes than the answer.

Comment: see also: [Why don't questions get that much upvote love?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359703/839601)

Answer (score 21):

Good answers do not imply good questions. There are lots of examples throughout the site of very insightful, well-written answers to poorly-written questions that do not demonstrate any research or effort. The reverse is also true.

In short, each post needs to stand or fall on its own merit.

Comment: Not to mention the [Reversal badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) exists for a reason...

Comment: I agree with your response and I added more context in a new comment on my question. As the votes on my own question show, poor questions will be penalized (irrespective of the good answers), but good questions may not be given enough credit for the dialog they it create.

Comment: @Li357 many seem to think that [reasons for this badge are rather poor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277576/839601)