# Why do questions get answered but not upvoted?

Tags: discussion, upvotes

I was just looking at hot questions on StackOverflow and I saw this question:

[How to access to a multidimensional row by row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043094/how-to-access-to-a-multidimensional-row-by-row)

There are 4 answers and zero upvotes. So at a minimum, four registered SO users took the time to answer the question but not upvote. Why does the SO Meta community think this is the case? Is it a "bad" question? Or is it just the case that people only answer and don't think to upvote the question? Or is it typically the place for those who have the same question to upvote? Just curious.

Comment: Answering and voting are mostly unrelated. A question may be good, bad, or neutral, independently from whether it's worth answering.

Comment: Can't speak for this particular question, nor for those involved on that question, but in my POV, a question being answerable doesn't always mean it's good enough to merit an upvote.

Comment: Looking at the link... With one exception, all who answered have very little reputation and are probably relatively new to the site, so they may not even know about up-voting or may not even be able to. There's one person with more than 1000 rep points, who *might* know about up-voting, but if the person doesn't think the question was worthy of an upvote... <shrug>

Comment: There are actually three options when it comes to quality voting: upvote, downvote and no vote. The latter is exactly my choice for questions which fall in a "meh" category. This is definitely such a question. It's written good enough, very clear. But you should not have to ask it if you spend enough time reading about arrays.

Comment: New contributors are not exempt from downvotes on their posts.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379704/1233251

Comment: Why do you allege that the downvotes are because of the duplicate?

Comment: If you disagree with the dupe closure, editing a mini-rant into your question isn't going to help your case.

Comment: My main point was it is not obvious from the title that this is a duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359703/why-dont-questions-get-that-much-upvote-love. I'd edit it, but I cannot. My title is much more clear. When you search for my title, the answer asked before, does not show up in the first page of results. That's all.

Comment: @ScottSkiles It is great that your title is more clear - users with the same problem will find your question and will be able to follow the link to the duplicate. Isn't this the whole point of duplicates to provide more possible search targets? Why do you object?

Comment: This is a good question. Yet it has only downvotes. It did trigger loads of interest though. +1 for me. The question is not about arrays, for those who missed that. The question has been asked by a user who would like to have an answer, or at least some opinions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't speak for others, but for myself, my thought process about voting and answering are completely different.

For voting:

1. Does the question show research effort? No research == down vote.
2. Is the question an obvious duplicate? (see #1--if it is, it demonstrates lack of research)
3. Is it clear what is being asked? If not, down vote
4. Is it clear what you've tried? (Complete code, error messages, etc)? if not, downvote
5. Is it easy to read? Well formatted, understandable grammar (I don't expect perfection, most people aren't English natives). If not, down vote

A negative response to these questions can earn a downvote from me.

Then finally:

- Should the OP have been reasonably expected to answer the question on their own without asking on SO?

If the answer to this question is "yes", I won't up vote, but I won't necessarily down vote, either.

As for answering, my thought process goes something like this:

1. Is it off-topic? If so, VtC and don't answer.
2. Is this a duplicate? If so, VtC, and don't answer.
3. Do I know the answer, and have the time to provide an adequate answer? If so, answer.

So, you see, the two actions (voting and answering) are almost entirely unrelated. The only relation they have to each other is about the question of duplicate questions.

This means there are times when I down-vote *and* answer (I know the answer, but it's poorly asked/researched, but not a duplicate), and there are times when I neither up- nor down-vote and answer. There are also times when I up-vote and answer.  But by far the most common: I either up-vote or down-vote, but don't answer, simply because I don't know the answer myself!

Comment: It's also possible to just forget to upvote.